# SendGrip Emails Won't Send

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer and am unable to send emails when configuring it to use my SendGrip credentials. Here is my sendEmail function:

```
public function sendEmail($to, $subject, $message)
{
    $mail = new \PHPMailer();

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'apikey';

    $mail->Password = 'removed';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->setFrom('removed@email.com');
    $mail->addAddress($to);

    $mail->isHTML(false);

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        throw new MailerException();
    }
}
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with this function?

Thanks,

Comment: What happens? What error do you get? And why not use the official SDK? https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

Comment: There is no error. I've tried the official SDK too and had the same result I'm afraid.

Comment: That sounds like a successful send, then. Does it show up in https://app.sendgrid.com/email_activity ?

Comment: The first one did, thereafter they don't. Nor do I receive any emails in my inbox.

Comment: Try sending to a different address (maybe you used Sendgrid's unsubscribe functionality - check the various options under "Suppressions" in the dashboard https://app.sendgrid.com/suppressions/global_unsubscribes) and check the spam folder. That it worked once means it probably isn't the code or the API.